# Is it alright if I read Quran using my tablet?

Tags: quran

My question is that, I have a tablet and I have installed Quran app in my tablet, is it OK to read Quran from my tablet?

- The thing which actually concerns me is that I also use my device for interent browsing, during which some very inappropriate content comes up on the screen even if I don't want it to, so is it ok if I read the Holy Quran on that same screen?
- I also listen to songs from time to time. So is it alright if I play the audio recitation of Holy Quran through the same speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Logically and commonly it won't be haram, Since this 
is like reciting the Quran through TV. but the remarkable point is that in case of being the possibility of encountering haram pics, rationally it could be haram.
Since this is not mandatory for you to recite the Quran (through it or..), accordingly it is more logical not to risk...

Regarding your second question, apparently it is not haram, but to keep the respect and the holiness of the Holy Quran you'd better leave it.