# Can I recites Quran Pak on mobile phone or any other electronic device in crowd?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, quran-recitation, reading-quran

As I am a student and I have to go for my classes in the early morning. In the Holy month of Ramadan I wanted to reciting the Quran on daily basis 4 to 5 times. But as the tough schedule it becomes a little bit difficult for me to recite. But if I have the Quran Pak (30 Paras) in my phone is it ok to recite these with having ablution in crowd?

Comment: This has been addressed and answered several times see: [Can we complete quran by reading from book and from device](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/can-we-complete-quran-by-reading-from-book-and-then-from-device), [Physical qur'an and mobile qur'an](]https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/physical-quran-and-mobile-quran) and [Is it alright if i read qur'an using my tablet?]https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/is-it-alright-if-i-read-quran-using-my-tablet?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you so much as these answers are quite satisfied.